# MFC - Getting device context of a specific window

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

I am new to MFC and trying to understand MFC's device context and UI threads.

I have created a UI Thread which opens a window. (I created a dialog class and i have called the doModal() in the thread's InitInstance.

And now from this UI thread i am creating one more WORKER thread.

I want to access the window opened by the UI thread from the worker thread.

Please suggest me how i could do that. I searched a lot over internet and i did'nt get proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mess with UI objects from the worker thread. The best thing to do in this case is do whatever you need in the worker thread and once aresult is available inform the UI thread. This can be done with a CWnd.PostMessage with a costom WM_...

The UI thread has to handle this message and do the required UI handling.

Comment: but i want to draw some waves on the dialog window of UI thread from the worker thread. Wont i be able to do that ever?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx you could syncronize access to graphic resources, but the problem is that thare are many accesses to GDIs functions that are our of your control. So you are better off passing the waves coordinates to UI thread and do the drawing from there.

Comment: Ok.. i understand this. Thnx for helping me out. But i have one more clarification. More than one UI thread can't open a same window dialog. Correct ?

Comment: Yes, correct. Normally all the GUI is handled by one thread (even if you have several windows), while you can have many worker threads.

Comment: OK.got it. Thank you.